# Declaring variable (name) containing another variable name in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am getting stuck here:

```
$file = gci C:\...\test\ | %{$_.name}
for ($i=0; $i -lt 100; $i++) {
  $array_$i =  gc C:\...\test\$($file[$i])
}
```

I am just trying to create multiple arrays for each text file in the directory.

Everything is working fine except the array name being declared - `$array_$i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would pick one of the suggestions already presented. Using some kind of collection data structure usually greatly simplifies handling a number of distinct, but similar items.

- Create an [array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41544021/1630171):

  ```
  $array = @()
  Get-ChildItem C:\...\test | Select-Object -First 100 | ForEach-Object {
    $array += ,@(Get-Content $_.FullName)
  }
  ```

  Running the `Get-Content` call in an array subexpression and prepending it with the unary comma operator ensures that you append a nested array instead of each element being appended individually:

  ```
  [
    [ 'foo', 'bar', ... ],
    [ 'baz', ... ],
    ...
  ]
  ```

  rather than

  ```
  [
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'baz',
    ...
  ]
  ```
- Create a [hashtable of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41539979/1630171):

  ```
  $ht = @{}
  Get-ChildItem C:\...\test | Select-Object -First 100 | ForEach-Object {
    $ht[$_.Name] = Get-Content $_.FullName
  }
  ```

  Using a hashtable is preferable if you need to be able to look up content by a particular key (in this example the filename) instead of an index.

  ```
  {
    'something': [ 'foo', 'bar', ... ],
    'other':     [ 'baz', ... ],
    ...
  }
  ```

  Note that you'll have to choose a different key if you have duplicate filenames, though (e.g. in different subfolders).

If, however, for some reason you *must* create individual variables for each content array you can do so with the [`New-Variable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-variable) cmdlet:

```
$i = 0
Get-ChildItem C:\...\test | Select-Object -First 100 | ForEach-Object {
  New-Variable -Name "array_$i" -Value (Get-Content $_.FullName)
  $i++
}
```

Comment: At first I went for the third option as it was looking perfect for my case but the arrays that were dynamically created were not giving any output, none.
I checked it is working fine for single array but not working in loop when combining with $i. It is also not giving any error on execution.

At second I went for the nesting (first one) as it was also meeting my purpose.
And it worked well. I can call files data based on indexing. Fine.
But my goal still remaining.

Comment: My goal is -

To call each file data based on indexing from nested array and remove last three lines.
So-
`$array = New-Object Sytem.Collections.Arraylist;
Get-ChildItem C:\...\test  | ForEach-Object {
  $array += ,@(Get-Content $_.FullName)
};

$array[0].removerange($array[0].count-2,2)`

But it throws error that removerange is not recognised.
I checked -
$array[0] | gm
and removerange method was indeed not there. Just Remove and Removeat.

How to proceed for this?

Comment: Ok. I marked the answer.
But just let me know how to get it done( removerange() method ).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$array += ,[Collections.ArrayList]@(Get-Content $_.FullName)` should probably suffice. If you need further help please post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell doesn't support variable variables (like `php` for example).

Use a hash table instead:

```
$files = gci C:\...\test\ | % {$_.Name}
$fileArrays = @{}
for ($i=0;$i -lt $files.Count; $i++){ 
    $fileArrays[$i] =  gc C:\...\test\$($file[$i]) 
}
```

Depending on what the purpose is, I would probably use the file name as the key instead. You're routine can also be simplified by:

```
$fileArrays = @{}
Get-ChildItem C:\...\test\ |ForEach-Object {
    $fileArrays[$_.Name] = Get-Content $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: Command runs but it is giving nothing.

$fileArrays[0] ................... no output

Comment: Which approach are you using? The first or the second?

Comment: The first approach.

Comment: I will still suggest you to use `arraylist` in this case. Then adding into that will be easy by using just the dot method.

Comment: The second approach works. I have name,value pairs of files and data in hash table.
But it is complex to make a loop to call the hash object values for further operations as it does not use indexing.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this script easy to add your file in your array :

```
$array =New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
dir c:\testpath | %{$content = gc $_.FullName;$array.Add($content) > $null}
```

Comment: But it will not create a nested array. I need it to be nested or different dynamic arrays because I have to do modifications in each file.

Comment: @iamsmith41 : you can declare 2 array and make it nested .