# Determining object type

Tags: powershell, object-type

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539881/declaring-variable-name-containing-another-variable-name-in-powershell) we resolved our issue but there was one point that I have not learned yet.

Below comments in the above post:

> My goal is - To call each file data based on indexing from nested array and remove last three lines. So- 
>   `$array = New-Object Sytem.Collections.Arraylist; Get-ChildItem C:\...\test | ForEach-Object { $array += ,@(Get-Content $_.FullName) }; $array[0].removerange($array[0].count-2,2)` 
>   But it throws error that removerange is not recognised. I checked - `$array[0] | gm` and removerange method was indeed not there. Just Remove and Removeat. How to proceed for this? *- iamsmith41 Jan 11 at 22:14*
>
> @iamsmith41 `Get-Content` returns a `System.Array`, not a `System.Collections.ArrayList`. The former doesn't have a `RemoveRange()` method. Also, please don't move the target. If one of the answers resolves the problem described in your current question: please consider accepting that answer. If you have a new or followup question: please post a new question. *- Ansgar Wiechers Jan 11 at 23:33*
>
> Ok. I marked the answer. But just let me know how to get it done( removerange() method ). Thanks in advance. *- iamsmith41 2 days ago*
>
> `$array += ,[Collections.ArrayList]@(Get-Content $_.FullName)` should probably suffice. If you need further help please post a new question. *- Ansgar Wiechers 2 days ago*

---

How to know the object type like above that I have to use is `Collections.ArrayList` and so on? How to know that this is a `System.Array` and not `System.Collections.ArrayList`, etc.?

Comment: `($expression).GetType().FullName` or `[Type]::GetTypeArray((,($expression)))[0].FullName`.

Answer (score 37):

You can determine the type of an object via its [`GetType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) method:

```
PS C:\> (Get-Item '.').GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                           BaseType
-------- -------- ----                           --------
True     True     DirectoryInfo                  System.IO.FileSystemInfo

PS C:\> (Get-Item '.').GetType().FullName
System.IO.DirectoryInfo
```

or by using the [`Get-Member`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) cmdlet:

```
PS C:\> Get-Item '.' | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.IO.DirectoryInfo

Name                MemberType     Definition
----                ----------     ----------
Mode                CodeProperty   System.String Mode{get=Mode;}
Create              Method         void Create(), void Create(System.Securi...
CreateObjRef        Method         System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef CreateObj...
CreateSubdirectory  Method         System.IO.DirectoryInfo CreateSubdirecto...
...
```

The former provides meta information about an object, like its name, base type, which assembly its from, etc. (pipe the output of `GetType()` into `Format-List *` to get a full list).

The latter is mainly for obtaining information about the members (properties and methods) of an object (or the static members of a class if you use the parameter `-Static`). Note that if you want information about the members of a collection object you must use `Get-Member -InputObject $col` instead just `$col | Get-Member`, because using the pipeline would unroll the collection and you'd get the members of the collection elements rather than those of the collection object itself.

Once you know a class you'd normally look up further information in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms310241), e.g. by feeding a class or member name into your preferred search engine.

Comment: You can also do `(Get-Item '.').GetType() -eq [System.IO.FileSystemInfo])`, at least in PS5

Comment: @jpaugh If you're already using PowerShell v5 you'd do `(Get-Item .) -is [System.IO.FileSystemInfo]`. That is only for checking if the object is of a specific type, though, not for finding out the type when you don't know it beforehand.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That actually works in a case where `-eq` does not, namely `$value -is [PSCustomObject]` (whereas fully spelling it out (as in `$value.GetType() -eq [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]`) would otherwise be required.

Answer (score 3):

To get the Type name of a Object: `(Get-Service | Get-Member)[0].TypeName`

Answer (score 3):

You could also simply test the type of object using `-is`

```
if ($array -is [Array]) {# then ok
  Write-Output 'Array'
}

if ($array -is [System.Collections.Arraylist] {# then not ok
  Write-Output 'ArrayList'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for looking at the type you can do:

```
expression | get-member
```

but if you can remove last 3 lines to file you can do it:

```
$yourfile='c:\temp\histo3.txt'
$content=Get-Content $yourfile
$content[0..[Math]::abs($content.Count - 4)] | Set-Content $yourfile
```